# disk full on WinXp Home keeps users from logging into accounts

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, login

PC ran out of HDD space and now users can't log into accounts.

Took drive out and put it in another PC to free up space (7.8 GB free of 80GB)

Put drive back in original PC.  Boots up, Windows log in screen comes up, log into account and then windows looks like it's logging in with user profile, but then closes that login session and goes back to log in screen. This happens for all accounts even in Safe mode and even for the administrator account, since I tried logging into that account.

When HDD was in the other PC, I noticed that there were a number of Temp folders in the User account folder, Temp.Desktop, Temp.Desktop1, Temp.Desktop2, Temp.Desktop3. Were these created when the HDD was full??

How to recover login sessions??  Delete Temp.Desktop folders and reboot??

Answer (score 1):

Your computers `userinit.exe` is corrupted, replace the `userinit.exe` file in `C:\Windows\System32\Userinit.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\Dllcache\Userinit.exe` (You may skip this).

If it's still not working and if you are in a network environment, log on to a networked computer and run `Regedit.exe`.

Select `File > Connect Remote Registry`. Type computer name (infected computer) and navigate to the following location in registry of destination in infected computer:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Check if the string `userinit` is available and it's data value is `c:\windows\system32\userinit.exe`.

If not available please create the same.

Restart your (infected) computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to free some space on the hard drive. Plug the hard drive into a second machine as a secondary hard drive. Or if you have a external USB hard drive adapter you can use that too. But one the hard drive is connected as a secondary drive then you can go into the disk and clear all the temp files that it has been creating. Make sure you have at least 10 or 15 GB free. Then put the hard drive back into the computer as the primary and then see if you can log onto it. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I already freed up 7.8 GB on the HD up from the 80MB that was there from previous. That should be more than enough. What about removing the Temp.Desktop files in the user accounts that are left there from previous attempts to log in??